# Implement jwplayer on Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, jwplayer6

I want to implement jwplayer on an emberjs app, i use bower to install jwplayer and i include it on ember cli build.

> app.import('bower_components/jwplayer/jwplayer.js');

The problem is when im trying on the application route to setup the jwplayer:

```
init() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    jwplayer.key='t7jmHu1/RAgJaW/NYESUcyMbUjuFcEeBqDTr/Q==';

    jwplayer("video").setup({
        file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/nhYDGoyh-kNspJqnJ.mp4"
    });
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: you need to ensure `video` DOM element should be ready before calling setup method. So create component and include it in any application.hbs and in `didInsertElement` method you can write your code..

Answer (score 0):

It's generally preferable to do this type of setup within a component. Doing so gives you much better control over when external plugins like this are loaded and unloaded.

See the discussion of third party libraries on this page (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/) about halfway down the page. You'll also want to make sure you clean up use of your library in the `willDestroyElement` hook so that you don't end up with multiple "ghost" versions of your library floating around in memory ...